# Is there a type for empty array in sql

Tags: sql, arrays, syntax, grammar, ansi-sql

Does ANSI sql have any implementation details on what the type is of an array with zero non-null elements? Some examples:

```
[]
[null, null]
[[], [], []]
[[null],[null]]
```

If not, is there any agreement on how it should be implemented? As an example Postgres gives an error on an empty array (makes sense) but casts it to text on an array with only null elements (doesn't make sense):

```
postgres=# select pg_typeof(array[]);
ERROR:  cannot determine type of empty array
HINT:  Explicitly cast to the desired type, for example ARRAY[]::integer[].

postgres=# select pg_typeof(array[null]);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 text[]
```

My thinking was to return something like `"undefined"` instead of an error, but I wonder if that is a valid approach or not.

Comment: I don't really have an answer here; my sense is that every implementation of SQL with arrays implements them in subtly different ways, either not compatible with standard SQL, or extending standard SQL functionality, or both. In particular, I suspect that the use of a literal array constructor in a context in which the type of the array is not deducible is not permitted in standard SQL. And it seems that in some contexts, standard SQL does not permit NULL element values in arrays, but I didn't find a source which clearly states in what contexts NULL elements are permitted. Good luck.

Comment: Personally, I would raise an error if it is impossible to determine the type of a non-empty array from the context. It seems like a bug-in-waiting. Empty arrays, on the other hand, do have their uses even if their precise type is indeterminate, but I think postgres is within its rights to reject the call to `pg_typeof`, but I would expect it to allow the use of an empty array of indeterminate type in an array concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

In ANSI SQL the array was introduced in [SQL99 standard version, and then it was extended in SQL2003 and on](https://farrago.sourceforge.net/design/CollectionTypes.html).

Best to my knowledge, **there is no direct answer to your question in standard docs**. I mean, the standard has no restriction over what type of array should be `[NULL, NULL]` for instance.

I would say, if you can, do not count on ANSI SQL please. I mean, that [ANSI SQL in general is somewhat hypothetical](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/ansi-sql-is-dead). At least, I do not know a single vendor that fully implement the SQL standard (well, *maybe*, but not actually, except MS SQL Server I guess), **especially in such a particular and concrete parts**. So even if you have found something in ANSI standard, I would not count on it.

Comment: SQL Server, even version 2022, is still missing **a lot** of features and capabilities in ISO SQL; interestingly the online docs list all the nonconforming parts of SQL Server, and there's a lot of them: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_standards/ms-tsqliso02/b909df7f-14fb-499e-83a8-0f42f94b2160 - e.g. deferrable constraints, domains, array types, even stuff like operators and syntax is still divergent (e.g. `CONCAT` vs `||`). etc - support for `DISTINCT FROM` and `STRING_SPLIT` with preserved ordinals wasn't added until this year.